# How to document *args parameter for method? [Python]

Tags: python, numpy, documentation, docstring

How do document a method arguments using NumPy (PEP 257) convention when it contains **args* parameter?

For example, I have such a method in my class:

```
def add_seis(self, *args, timeout=-1):
    '''
    Add new Seis to live feed
    
    The user can provide an already defined Seis object
    or simply symbol, exchange and interval values. If
    latter is provided then new Seis object will be 
    created and returned after adding it to the live feed.
    Timeout value can be used to specify maximum wait time
    for the method to return.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    ???
    '''
```

What should go under parameters section? How is the correct way to document this if my intention is to make sure able to either provide a single object (Seis) or three objects (str, str, Interval) based on which the same object would then be internally created?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you state the 'supported' argument options (one or three).  But I feel this is an opinion-based question rather than something that needs fixing.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why do you find it a hazard? Do you maybe have a better way how you would solve this?

Comment: "hazard a guess" is a figure of speech.  My apologies for the confusion.  What I meant by that was "I'd guess that would you'd do is specify in the Parameters section, the supported options, i.e.  1 argument,  and 3 arguments.   That said, I have no 'better' way of solving this as it's not particularly ( I believe) a clear cut answer.

Comment: Usually, I'd denote it as a single argument. That argument is a `Union` of either a `Seis` or a three-tuple of the ingredients. So `seis: Union[Seis, Ingredients]` where `Ingredients` might be a `namedtuple`

Comment: @C.Nivs I don't understand the Union part. Doesn't Union only work with set types?

Comment: @rongard `Union` denotes multiple types. So if you wanted to take a string or `pathlib.Path`, you could do `Union[str, Path]`. `Optional` is like a `Union[T, None]`

Comment: Okay, I looked up Union in typing module now, had not used it before. But this way the user would have to provide Ingredients object like add_seis(Ingredients(symbol, exchange, interval))? I guess we cannot simply provide add_seis(symbol, exchange, interval)?

Comment: The closest I got right now is that I defined method as follows: add_seis(seis : Union[Seis,list]). In this case the user can call method two ways: add_seis(seis_instance) or add_seis([symbol_str, exchange_str, interval_str]). Would be nice to be able to provide strings without casting to list, but at least this works and is somewhat elequant.